# Soft-raid with Windows Server (Redundancy on OS)

Tags: windows, software-raid, ovh, windows-server-2022

We lease bare-metal servers on OVH. We use Windows Server 2022 as OS on the servers.

OVH offers soft-raid for all of their servers. They do not offer hardware raid.

While it's generally possible to do a raid1 mirror raid on Windows Server, when you do that it does not include the EFI partition, and thus you don't actually have redundancy for the system. If one SSD goes out, the system will become unbootable.

Is there a workaround to this?

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution.
Manually create the efi partition on the second disk.
Expose the primary and secodary efi partitions with
drive letters.
Copy the content of the efi partition from the primary to the
secondary.

See details at: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/backup-and-storage/establish-boot-to-gpt-mirrors
(It seems that the above document from Microsoft has been written for Windows Server 2003, but it is still relevant)

I had one error when following the procedure in that Microsoft document. When copying the efi partition from the primary disk to the secondary disk, there was an error:
"BCD Sharing violation".
It was solved by copying the efi partition after booting the system to a recovery console (booting to command line recovery from Windows installation disk).

It could be solved by using the bcdedit /export command. This command might save you from having to use a recovery console, and complete the all process from the operating system. I haven't tried it though.